# How to trace all the http traffic of a standalone app

Tags: java, http, trace

I want to ask you how can I **trace all the 'http' traffic** triggered by a simple Java standalone application.

I run under openjdk version "**1.8.0_212**".

This doesn't works for me:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<path_to_file>/logging.properties
```

In the **logging.properties**:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = FINEST
```

Answer (score 0):

You say it doesn't work, but you don't specify what's the behaviour you are getting. You get no logs at all? You get some log traces but not all you would expect?

Nevertheless, here are some shots in the dark:

1. Try this in the logging.properties file:

   ```
   handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL
   ```
2. In the `java.util.logging.config.file` property, make sure to specify the full path (and not a relative one) to the logging.properties file
3. I assume when you say http traffic you really mean http and not https; in case you want to debug SSL connections (https), try passing the following property to the JVM:

   ```
   -Djavax.net.debug=all
   ```

If none of the above works, you may want to post a [minimal, self contained example](http://sscce.org/) along with the full command line used to run it.